# Google App Script to dynamically merge multiple sheets into a master

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet where I'm trying to merge data from multiple tabs.

Also

1. For the tabs that are in scope for merging I only need to merge the first 7 columns of the tabs into the master tab. (These tabs contain unstructured data beyond the first 7 tabs that I want to exclude
2. The workbook contains numerous tabs that I need to exclude
3. Over time the workbook will grow to include additional "in scope tabs" that will where the first 7 columns need to be merged so the script need to be dynamic to include these tabs.

I attempted to modify the following script posted by "TheMaster" but it would only pull in the first tab of data and throw an exception that the range size didn't match the data.  Also, .getDataRange can't seem to be constrained from pulling in all data from the in-scope sheets

```
//@OnlyCurrentDoc
function merge() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const arr = ss
    .getSheets()
    .filter(s => !s.getName().includes(['Master','Lookups','Resource Pivot','Clicktime Data']))//exclude out of scope sheets
    .flatMap(s => s.getDataRange().getValues());//map sheet to values and flatten it
  ss.getSheetByName('Master')
    .getRange(1, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length)
    .setValues(arr);
}
```

Any assistance or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about `These tabs contain unstructured data beyond the first 7 tabs that I want to exclude`, `so the script need to be dynamic to include these tabs.` and `.getDataRange can't seem to be constrained from pulling in all data from the in-scope sheets`. Can I ask you about the detail of them? By the way, about `includes()`, I think that [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) is useful.

Comment: @Tanaike I'll attempt to clarify things.    

The tabs that are in scope for merging have structured 2-dimensional data in the first 7 columns.  Essentially an array.  

There is additional data in these sheets after the first 7 columns that I do not want merged.

When using  .getDataRange  all data in the sheet is merged even the data I want to exlcude.

Thanks for the link.  I'll take a look.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I cannot understand about `structured 2-dimensional data` of `The tabs that are in scope for merging have structured 2-dimensional data in the first 7 columns.`.